# What is the purpose of instance Alternative IO?

Tags: haskell

This instance doesn't seem to behave properly:

```
> guard True <|> guard False

> guard False <|> guard False
*** Exception: user error (mzero)
```

One might argue that this cannot result in anything else. But why define such instance in the first place? Is there any good reason to result in `_|_` whenever evaluation does not make sense?

Comment: The main purpose is to make sure no one can agree on any laws whatsoever for `Alternative`.

Comment: What else would you expect to happen? If you are have alternatives around IO actions that might fail, if they all fail you get an IO error. I'm not sure I fully understand your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of the `Alternative` instance for `IO` is to combine `IO` actions that might fail (by causing an IO error or otherwise throwing an exception) into a single `IO` action that "tries" multiple actions in turn, accepting the first successful one, or -- if all actions fail -- fails itself.

So, something like this would work to read one or more lines (using `some`) from standard input or else (using `<|>`) complain if no lines are available:

```
main = (print =<< some getLine) <|> putStrLn "No input!"
```

or you could write something like:

```
readConfig :: IO Config
readConfig = readConfigFile "~/.local/myapp/config"
         <|> readConfigFile "/etc/myapp/config"
         <|> return defaultConfig
```

Given this, it makes perfect sense that:

```
guard False <|> guard False
```

represents an action that, when executed, must fail by generating an exception.  If it didn't, as @danidaz has pointed out, then executing the action:

```
guard False <|> guard False <|> putStrLn "success!"
```

wouldn't work to execute the third action.  Since `<|>` is left associative and tries its left action before its right, executing the value of this expression would just execute whatever successful action `guard False <|> guard False` represented (e.g., `return ()` or whatever) and never try `putStrLn "success!"`.

There's a subtlety here that may be throwing you off.  Contrary to first appearances, the value of:

```
guard False <|> guard False
```

isn't `_|_` in the usual sense.  Rather it's a perfectly well defined IO action that, *if executed* will fail to terminate in the sense of throwing an exception.  That type of non-termination is still useful, though, because we can catch it (by adding another `<|>` alternative, for example!).

Also note, because you haven't supplied a better exception, a default exception of `userError "mzero"` is thrown.  If you had instead caused failure via:

```
ioError (userError "one") <|> ioError (userError "two")
```

you'd see that if all actions fail, the last exception thrown is the one that gets thrown by the composite action.

Comment: All answers are great but this one helped me to realize that running the IO action was the problem, not evaluation.

Answer (score 10):

[`asum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) from `Data.Foldable` can be useful to repeat a `IOException`-throwing action a number of times, until it succeeds or fails altogether:

```
import Data.Foldable (asum)
import Control.Monad
import Control.Exception
import System.Random -- from the "random" package

diceRoll :: IO Int
diceRoll = do
    putStrLn "hi"
    r <- randomRIO (0,20)
    if r < 18
        then throwIO (userError (show r))
        else return r

main :: IO ()
main = do
    r <- asum $ take 7 $ repeat diceRoll
    print r
```

Given the "return the result of the first action that doesn't throw" semantics, `empty` must be an action that throws an exception. Otherwise it wouldn't work as a neutral element, for example in `empty <|> return 4`.

This is not *that* different from how the `Alternative` instance for `Maybe` behaves. There, `asum` returns the first non-`Nothing` value in a sequence of `Maybe`s.

(Another "strange" `empty` is the one for the `Alternative` instace of [`Concurrently`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.1.1.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#t:Concurrently), which just waits forever. The `<|>` races two actions against each other.)

Answer (score 4):

While not explicitly documented with `Alternative`, instances should essentially obey the following laws:

```
pure x <|> y = pure x
empty <|> x = x
```

You can intuit this as implementing some notion of “truthiness” and “falsiness”, where `pure x` is always truthy and `empty` is always falsy.

For this to make any sense for `IO`, we need some notion of truthiness. There aren’t many good ones, but `IO` has the ability to handle exceptions, so we can define truthy `IO` actions as actions that produce a value and falsy `IO` actions as actions that throw exceptions. Therefore, `(<|>)` for `IO` runs its first argument, and if it produces a value without throwing an exception, it returns the value; otherwise, it returns its second argument.

We now have a definition of `(<|>)` for `IO`, but what should `empty` be? Well, `empty` must be falsy, and we have defined falsiness on `IO` as “throwing an exception”. Therefore, `empty` must be an action that throws an exception.

The `guard` function is very simple, since it is just `pure ()` when given `True` and `empty` when given `False`. This means your examples are really equivalent to the following:

```
empty <|> pure ()
empty <|> empty
```

In the first example, `empty` throws, so `(<|>)` catches it and returns `pure ()`, which obviously produces `()`. In the second example, the same thing happens, except that the second argument is also `empty`, so the expression’s result also throws an exception.