# Why is there difference between throw and throwIO?

Tags: haskell, exception, io-monad, alternative-functor

I am trying to get a firm grasp of exceptions, so that I can improve my [conditional loop implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57360857/). To this end, I am staging various experiments, throwing stuff and seeing what gets caught.

This one surprises me to no end:

```
% cat X.hs
module Main where

import Control.Exception
import Control.Applicative

main = do
    throw (userError "I am an IO error.") <|> print "Odd error ignored."
```

```
% ghc X.hs && ./X
...
X: user error (I am an IO error.)
```

```
% cat Y.hs
module Main where

import Control.Exception
import Control.Applicative

main = do
    throwIO (userError "I am an IO error.") <|> print "Odd error ignored."
```

```
% ghc Y.hs && ./Y
...
"Odd error ignored."
```

I thought that the Alternative should ignore exactly IO errors. *(Not sure where I got this idea from, but I certainly could not offer a non-IO exception that would be ignored in an Alternative chain.)* So I figured I can hand craft and deliver an IO error. Turns out, whether it gets ignored depends on the packaging as much as the contents: if I `throw` an IO error, it is somehow *not anymore* an IO error.

I am completely lost. Why does it work this way? Is it intended? The definitions lead deep into the GHC internal modules; while I can more or less understand the meaning of disparate fragments of code by themselves, I am having a hard time seeing the whole picture.

Should one even use this Alternative instance if it is so difficult to predict? Would it not be better if it silenced any synchronous exception, not just some small subset of exceptions that are *defined* in a specific way and *thrown* in a specific way?

Comment: The docs state that "[the two functions are subtly different](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throwIO)".

Comment: But whoever wrote that had weird ideas about the meaning of "subtly".

Comment: It is too subtle for me, I do not get the difference. Where in my code is `seq`?

Comment: Using the `Alternative` instance of `IO` for that kind of loop is unidiomatic. In Java, it would be like throwing an exception at the end of a for loop's body in order to advance to the next iteration.

Comment: @danidiaz Well then what is idiomatic with Alternative IO?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov In my opinion, not a lot. Perhaps retries when the action we want to retry *already* throws exceptions, we don't want to inspect or analyze the exceptions thrown, and we want to exit with an exception if all the retries fail.

Comment: In my opinion, the really annoying thing is that we don't have separate `catch`, `catchIO`, and `catchFrom` corresponding to `throw`, `throwIO`, and `throwTo`. Imprecise, precise, and asynchronous exceptions are all quite different. The most annoying thing is that there's no reliable way to distinguish asynchronous exceptions from imprecise ones in catching, when they have important differences. In particular, the distinction affects thunk resumption, and there's no reliable way to rethrow a caught exception with the same synchronous/asynchronous status.

Comment: @dfeuer I am thinking `catches action [someAsyncRethrow, someHandle]` is your way to distinguish asynchronous exceptions. I cannot undersand the part about thunk, and I do not understand why you say there is no reliable way to rethrow an exception with the same status. I thought whether an exception is synchronous or asynchronous is written on the box? When it matches `SomeAsyncException`, it is asynchronous, and if you rethrow it, it is still asynchronous. Am I missing something big here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have

```
x :: Integer
```

That means that `x` should be an integer, of course.

```
x = throw _whatever
```

What does that mean? It means that there was supposed to be an `Integer`, but instead there’s just a mistake.

Now consider

```
x :: IO ()
```

That means `x` should be an I/O-performing program that returns no useful value. Remember, `IO` values are just *values*. They are values that just happen to represent imperative programs. So now consider

```
x = throw _whatever
```

That means that there was supposed to be an I/O-performing program there, but there is instead just a mistake. `x` is not a program that throws an error—there *is* no program. Regardless of whether you’ve used an `IOError`, `x` isn’t a valid `IO` program. When you try to execute the program

```
x <|> _whatever
```

You have to execute `x` to see whether it throws an error. But, you *can’t* execute `x`, because it’s not a program—it’s a mistake. Instead, everything explodes.

This differs significantly from

```
x = throwIO _whatever
```

Now `x` is a valid program. It is a valid program that always happens to throw an error, but it’s still a valid program that can actually be executed. When you try to execute

```
x <|> _whatever
```

now, `x` is executed, the error produced is discarded, and `_whatever` is executed in its place. You can also think of there being a difference between computing a program/figuring out what to execute and actually executing it. `throw` throws the error while computing the program to execute (it is a "pure exception"), while `throwIO` throws it during execution (it is an "impure exception"). This also explains their types: `throw` returns any type because all types can be "computed", but `throwIO` is restricted to `IO` because only programs can be executed.

This is further complicated by the fact that you *can* catch the pure exceptions that occur while executing `IO` programs. I believe this is a design compromise. From a theoretical perspective, you *shouldn't* be able to catch pure exceptions, because their presence should always be taken to indicate programmer error, but that can be rather embarrassing, because then you can only handle external errors, while programmer errors cause everything to blow up. If we were perfect programmers, that would be fine, but we aren't. Therefore, you are allowed to catch pure exceptions.

```
is :: [Int]
is = []

-- fails, because the print causes a pure exception
-- it was a programmer error to call head on is without checking that it,
-- in fact, had a head in the first place
-- (the program on the left is not valid, so main is invalid)
main1 = print (head is) <|> putStrLn "Oops"
-- throws exception

-- catch creates a program that computes and executes the program print (head is)
-- and catches both impure and pure exceptions
-- the program on the left is invalid, but wrapping it with catch
-- makes it valid again
-- really, that shouldn't happen, but this behavior is useful
main2 = print (head is) `catch` (\(_ :: SomeException) -> putStrLn "Oops")
-- prints "Oops"
```

Comment: The last paragraph is a bit difficult.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Better?

Comment: Yes, way better. I was a bit confused because there is [another definition of impure exceptions](https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/tutorial/exceptions) out there and I was not able to align what I read there with what you said.

Answer (score 6):

`throw` is a generalization of `undefined` and `error`, it's meant to throw an exception in pure code. When the value of the exception does not matter (which is most of the time), it is denoted by the symbol ⟘ for an "undefined value".

`throwIO` is an IO action which throws an exception, but is not itself an undefined value.

The documentation of [`throwIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:throwIO) thus illustrates the difference:

```
throw e   `seq` x  ===> throw e
throwIO e `seq` x  ===> x
```

The catch is that `(<|>)` is defined as [`mplusIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.html#mplusIO) which uses [`catchException`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.html#catchException) which is a strict variant of `catch`. That strictness is summarized as follows:

```
⟘ <|> x = ⟘
```

hence you get an exception (and `x` is never run) in the `throw` variant.

Note that, without strictness, an "undefined action" (i.e., `throw ... :: IO a`) actually behaves like an action that throws from the point of view of `catch`:

```
catch (throw   (userError "oops")) (\(e :: SomeException) -> putStrLn "caught")  -- caught
catch (throwIO (userError "oops")) (\(e :: SomeException) -> putStrLn "caught")  -- caught
catch (pure    (error     "oops")) (\(e :: SomeException) -> putStrLn "caught")  -- not caught
```

Comment: @IgnatInsarov The documentation for `throwIO` states that it should be preferred to `throw` when working in a `IO` context.

Comment: If anything `throw` is the abomination. If you have exceptions throwing them is a perfectly fine action to do, that's `throwIO`.

Comment: @danidiaz Does it per chance also explain why? I have kinda read what it says on the box, — maybe twice, — but I am still not seeing the picture.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia But I can catch `throw`n exceptions just as well. We have exceptions occuring in pure computations anyway, have we not? Like `ArithException` for instance?

Comment: But we also can't really get rid of `throw` (or `error` or `undefined`) either. In a non-strict language with general recursion (Haskell), you will have "undefined values" at least because of nontermination, so you might as well keep the ability of throwing exceptions instead of going into an infinite loop and make the best out of it.

Comment: `ArithException` isn't really an exception; it's an ordinary data type that gets used in a pure *simulation* of exceptions. `throw`, on the other hand, raises a real "catch it or the runtime gives up" exception (which are called IO exceptions only because they only get generated during the execution of an IO action, not because they are values some `IO` type).

Comment: What do you mean @chepner? You can `throw (Overflow :: ArithException)`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I think of it as `throw` *generating* an exception using information carried by `Overflow`, rather than `Overflow` *being* the actual exception.

Comment: There's also an `IOException` type that's distinct from `ArithException`, so I wouldn't take the denomination "IO exception" so lightly.

Answer (score 3):

The rest of this answer may not be entirely correct. But fundamentally, the difference is this: `throwIO` terminates and returns an `IO` action, while `throw` does *not* terminate.

---

As soon as you try to evaluate `throw (userError "...")`, your program aborts. `<|>` never gets a chance to look at its first argument to decide if the second argument should be evaluated; in fact, it never *gets* the first argument, because `throw` didn't return a value.

With `throwIO`, `<|>` isn't evaluating anything; it's creating a new `IO` action which, when it *does* get executed, will first look at its first argument. The runtime can "safely" execute the `IO` action and see that it does not, in fact, provide a value, at which point it can stop and try the other "half" of the `<|>` expression.

Comment: I like to think of Haskell as a purely function DSL (with no exceptions) for composing IO programs, which are written in a language you have little direct access to. Li-yao puts it nicely: `throw` lets you raise an exception inside the IO interpreter directly from the pure Haskell code.